# Instantiate object for keeping the web session active?

Tags: python, object, web-scraping

I am trying to bring my idea into code where I would like to create a session object "s", which could be used or called whenever I need. I came with this so far, but not sure if this is correct way and will fill up my expectation.

simple function with BS soup from page:

```
def get_info(html_soup):
    print('whole page ?', html_soup)
```

object for keeping session ?

```
class LoginLogout:
    # user = 'something'
    # password = 'something'
    server = 'some address'
    LOGIN_LINK = 'some web link'

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    def login(self, user, password, server):
        payload_data = {'user': user, 'pass': password, 'server': server}
        print(self.s.post(LOGIN_LINK, payload_data))
        # return self.s.post(LOGIN_LINK, payload_data)

    def get_info_bar(self):
        get_info(self.s.get('some web link').text)

    def update(self):
        function for the update ??? (I am not sure, if I can even call here a function)    

    def logout(self):
        response = self.s.get('some web link')
        self.s.close()
        print(response)
```

And my idea is, during scraping some web page, I would like to login to the page and with existing, created session as "s", want to do something like this:

```
new_var = LoginLogout()
new_var.get_info_bar()
print('what is going on? ', new_var)
```

To put it simply: I would like to keep session active, and get required pages scraped anytime I request it.

Ouhg, I am really sorry. Here is the modified question:

I've got there some code to call functions, where one is for login, others for functionality, and one for logout (maybe others come later):

```
if switch_parameter == "login":
    log_var = LoginLogout()
    log_var.login(USER, PASSWORD, SERVER)
    print(log_var.s.get('part of requested page'))
elif switch_parameter == "start":
    start()
elif switch_parameter == "stop":
    stop()
elif switch_parameter == "update":
    upd_var = LoginLogout()
    upd_var.get_info_bar()

elif switch_parameter == "logout":
    logout()
else:
    pass
```

Will it work if I call the "s" via function ? or should I assign it to some global variable ?

Many thanks for any kind of help.
(still beginner here)

Comment: That's the purpose of `requests.Session()`.  It remembers your login cookie and sends it again with future requests.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it is log me into the webpage, but I am not sure how should I call the "s" (with this request.Session) later in the program, when I need to get content from the page.

Comment: I've got there some code to call functions, where one is for login, others for functionality, and one for logout:
if switch_parameter == "login":
    log_var = LoginLogout()
    log_var.login(USER, PASSWORD, SERVER)
    print(log_var.s.get('part of requested page'))
elif switch_parameter == "start":
    start()
elif switch_parameter == "stop":
    stop()
elif switch_parameter == "update":
    upd_var = LoginLogout()
    upd_var.get_info_bar()

elif switch_parameter == "logout":
    logout()
else:
    pass
Will it work if I call the s via function ?

Comment: We can't read code in a comment.  Please modify the question.